# Job ads relevant to tags

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, jobs, advertising

I see a lot of job ads on SO, I've searched through them as well. It seems, however, that the ads are very broad in their targeting.

What I would like to see is ads based on tags.

First, it should display ads with relevant tags in your favorites before ads without relevant tags.

Second, it should place more weight on tags that you've got answer points in, allowing things that you're interested in or good at to be first.

This will keep the interesting stuff towards the top and encourage good answers within the community. It will also make the job lister happier, as they'll be able to get their listing seen by relevant developers faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Turns out we have served ads based on tag matching.  In A/B testing, location won out in terms of click-through rates (CTR) by a significant margin.

In your second suggestion you give more weight to tags people are active in.  Most users are active in the tags they mark as favorites, so it feels like these 2 suggestions are just two ways to go about doing the same thing.

Thank you for your suggestions, we are always looking for ways to increase the CTR on the job ads we serve.

Comment: Interesting information. Though, I think that putting weight on the tags users have answer points in would add a relevant weight. It would almost certainly have redundancy to their favorite tags, but I think that many users aren't as active in some of their favorite tags compared with their other favorites. Which potentially makes those tags more relevant. It seems that what is best for now is location, but I think in the future, it could be beneficial to combine tag matching users active tags with location. I'm not saying limit it strictly to those, of course, this would be more like sorting.